# SSH connection to Raspberry using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ssh, server

I want to fetch remote system's files from my iOS device by establishing SSH Connection using Swift and then some execute commands. I am able to connect through Mac terminal using below command:

ssh user@192.168.50.1

Which library/framework do I need to install. Also, any sample implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to connect to remote environment using NMSSH framework.

https://github.com/NMSSH/NMSSH